# Grow up just "fa fa" icon without background webkit-transform css

Tags: html, css

I have fa icons on my website and the small background behind that icons.
When I add the "transform: scale(1.2);" code to make icon bigger on hover, the background going big, too. How to solve this? :/

This is the whole code of that:

```css
#snav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 28%;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#snav ul { list-style: none; }

#snav * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#snav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fafaf9;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#snav .fa {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

#snav li span {
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
}

#snav li a:hover .fa { transform: scale(1.2); }

.snav li a:hover .fa {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2.2em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#snav li a:hover span { visibility: visible; }
#snav li span { background-color: #555; }

/* icons color and background before hover  */

#snav li .fa {
  background-color: #EEE;
  color: #555;
}

/* icons hover color */

#snav li a:hover .fa { color: #fafaf9; }

/* repeated colors from 1 to 10 each hover color repeated after 10 menu items */

#snav li:nth-child(10n+1) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+1) a:hover .fa { background-color: #3b2551; }

#snav li:nth-child(10n+2) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+2) a:hover .fa { background-color: #4EC5DB; }

#snav li:nth-child(10n+3) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+3) a:hover .fa { background-color: #3DC25D; }

#snav li:nth-child(10n+4) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+4) a:hover .fa { background-color: #99BE24; }

#snav li:nth-child(10n+5) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+5) a:hover .fa { background-color: #38c; }

#snav li:nth-child(10n+6) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+6) a:hover .fa { background-color: #3b5997; }

#snav li:nth-child(10n+7) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+7) a:hover .fa { background-color: #6a453a; }

#snav li:nth-child(10n+8) span,
#snav li:nth-child(10n+8) a:hover .fa { background-color: #0bbff2; }

#snav.en {
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

#snav.en li span { left: -100px; }

#snav.en li a:hover span { left: 35px; }
```

Comment: You're going to want to post some code showing what you're trying ASAP or this question is likely to get downvoted and closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

**transform: scale(1,2);**

Try to change the font-size of the icon.

**font-size: 10px;**

The transform may be interfering with other codes.

**Vote up, if helped !**